# table design in angular 6 with html

Tags: html, angular6

I need to design the table as below attached format using angular 6 with html.

[image]

The table needs to be displayed by grouping ID and Name attribute.I don't know how to merge the two cells of ID and Name.The values which are populating in table are in JSON format. Please help me to design this.

The values which are needs to be populated are:

```
Values:[
        {"ID:1","Name:"John","Maths":50,"Tamil":50,"English":50"},
        {"ID:1","Name:"John","Maths":98,"Tamil":45,"English":60"},
        {"ID:1","Name:"John","Maths":100,"Tamil":95,"English":95"}, 
        {"ID:2","Name:"Steve","Maths":60,"Tamil":40,"English":60"}, 
        {"ID:2","Name:"Steve","Maths":88,"Tamil":66,"English":44"}, 
        {"ID:3","Name:"Smith","Maths":60,"Tamil":44,"English":56"}, 
        {"ID:3","Name:"Smith","Maths":45,"Tamil":65,"English":78"}
       ]
```

My Solution:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="Table">
<div class="Heading">
<div class="Cell">
<p>ID</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<p>Name</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<p>Maths</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<p>Tamil</p>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<p>English</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Row" *ngFor="let set of setting.value ; let index = index">
<div class="Cell">{{set.ID}}</div>
<div class="Cell">{{set.Name}}</div>
<div class="Cell">{{set.Maths}}</div>
<div class="Cell" >{{set.Tamil}}</div>
<div class="Cell">{{set.English}}</div>
<div class="Cell">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default 
(click)="delete()">Delete</button>
</div>                              
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Custom group by filter:

```
@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})

export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(collection: any[], property1: string, property2: string): any[] {
if(!collection) {
return null;
}
const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
var property = current[property1] + current[property2]            
if(!previous[property] ) {               
previous[property] = [current];
} else {
previous[property].push(current);
}
return previous;
}, {});
return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: 
groupedCollection[key] }));
}
```

CSS:

```
.Table
{
display: table;
border-spacing: 5px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-right:50px;
margin-left: 50px;
border:  solid grey;
border-width: thin;
border-collapse: collapse;
align-self: left;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.Heading
{
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: bold;

    text-align: center;
    background-color:lightgrey

}
.Row
{
    display: table-row;

}
.Cell
{
    display: table-cell;

    border: solid grey;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;

}
```

Comment: you can use the rowspan attribute of table html element

Comment: You can try first add your efforts and then we can help

Comment: I had tried with custom group by filter..but the design is not as expected..
Script which i had tried:
 <div class="Row" *ngFor="let setting of settings | groupBy:'ID':'Name'">
 <div class="Row" *ngFor="let set of setting.value ; let index = index">
            <div class="Cell"  >{{set.ID}}</div>
                <div class="Cell" >{{set.Name}}</div>              
                <div class="Cell" >{{set.Maths}}</div>           
                <div class="Cell" >{{set.Tamil}}</div>
<div class="Cell">{{set.English}}</div></div></div>  @Justcode

Comment: @SowmiyaB — `<div class="Row">`?! **Write semantic HTML**. We have `<tr>` (and `<td>` etc). They support things like `rowspan`.

Comment: I wrote style for "Row" class in CSS. It is same as <tr>@Quentin

Answer (score -1):

u create a custom css class 
`.without-bottom-line { border-bottom: none !important}`

then you add it  conditionally

```
 <div class="Row" *ngFor="let setting of settings | groupBy:'ID':'Name'"> 
 <div class="Row" *ngFor="let set of setting.value ; let index = index"> 
 <div class="Cell" 
  [ngClass]="{ 'without-bottom-line ': setting.value[i].ID ==  
  setting.value[i+1].ID}">  
 {{set.ID}} </div> 
 <div class="Cell"
 [ngClass]="{ 'without-bottom-line ': setting.value[i].Name 
 ==  setting.value[i+1].Name}">
 {{set.Name}}</div>
 <div class="Cell" >{{set.Maths}}</div> <div class="Cell" >{{set.Tamil}}</div> 
 <div class="Cell">{{set.English}}</div></div></div>
```